# bind parameter and variable in the same pdo statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm new to binding parameters and variables in PDO. I will like to know, is it possible to bind both parameters in the form of `:id` and a variable `$datecreated` in the same `$stmt` binding statement? e.g.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO messages (msg_subject,msg_body,doctor_id,appointment_id,msg_status, date_created) VALUES ('APPOINTMENT BOOKING CONFIRMED','Dear :name,<br/>Your appointment id: :id has been booked successfully','1',':id','1',".$datecreated.")");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $params->name);
$stmt->bindParam(':id',$params->id);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask It's unclear what you are asking and what research you have done.

Comment: No, it won't work like that. I'd suggest creating the string with `sprintf`, then bind the new value created.

Comment: When a parameter is inserted, it automatically adds single quotes. So you're value `':id'` actually end up like `''1''`, which is invalid.

Comment: Same for `'Dear :name,<br/>Your appointment id: :id has been booked successfully'`

Comment: @bassxzero It does not add quotes. Instead, the API bypasses the quoting completely.

Comment: I'm not seeing what `$var` (mentioned in your question text) has to do with your code.

Comment: Binding values to placeholders in a SQL statement is NOT the same as interpolating variable values in a string in PHP.... you cannot use binding in this way to build a string in SQL

Comment: @Patrick Q I was referring to $datecreated but wrote $var before checking the code. the real challenge is i'm trying to mix both :id and $date in the same prepare statement but at the end i'm getting a Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "19": syntax error in my prepare statement.

Comment: @MarkBaker what do you intend i do? Please i'm new to PDO and was just following tutorials on how to use bindParam

Comment: You're going to have to build the `msg_body` string manually as a PHP variable using standard PHP interpolation; and bind that string to a placeholder..... but don't quote your placeholders (like `':id'`), that's one of the things that binding handles for you; and why not use a placeholder for your `$datecreated` as well, so you won't get errors from an unquoted date

Comment: @MarkBaker, if i'm going to do that, how do I bind the parameters of my appointment id and patient name which was passed using json into the php to the string? $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$params = json_decode($json)

Comment: I'm able to get it right now, I created the query separately and execute it like I use to when still using mysqli and it works so i don't need to bind it. But i still welcome any other ways of binding parameters cause most of the ways i got online ain't working for my php 5.2.0

Comment: @bassxzero, now i understand what you where saying, i  cant include it to the content of my query like that. I see where my error is. because when i tried it again but representing the whole parameter of my body with a single bind without adding the single quote, it worked! Thanks alot